# Unable to evaluate if not for python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing the program for python and I'm new with python. I'm stuck with problem where I need to achieve 'if Not' condition after some validation on my input data. Please anyone guide me what I'm doing wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks,

**Code**

```
    if(options == 1):
    print"Please enter degrees Fahrenheit:"
    val1 = input('')
    val2 = str(val1)
    commaExist = any([st in ',' for st in val2])
       if not commaExist:
       print"1"
       elif:
       print"2"
elif(options == 2):
    print"2p"
elif(options == 3):
    print"3p"
else:
    print"invalid"
```

Can anyone also please guide me is it the best approach to use input() instead to raw_input ? I need to validate my input only for numbers with decimal point and minus sign any other input would be an invalid. So is it a good approach to use any() ? or python give us any other methods too.

Comment: is the indent appeared in the code here is same as your ide ?

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting an error message, is your program running but not doing what you expect, what?

Comment: @Ramesh Thanks for your response. I'm getting an indentation error: expected on indented block

Answer (score 2):

why not just use:

```
if "," not in val2:
    print ("1")
else:
    print ("2")
```

BTW, the print statements without parenthesis will not work in Python 3, only Python 2. But I believe with the parens it works in both versions.

Comment: I have updated my question please have a look now. I'm using nested loops which doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
    print "Please enter degrees Fahrenheit:"
      val1 = input('')
      val2 = str(val1)
      commaExist = any([st in ',' for st in val2]) 
      if not commaExist: #<-- here is the issue
        print"1"
      else:
        print"2"
```

I think you're failing to indent the if statements, also you're using an elif without a bool. (I think you just need an else)

Comment: still I'm facing an exception indentation error: expected on indented block

Comment: I'd failed with the formatting on my post, any time you have a ':' the next part of the code needs to be indented.

Comment: Please have a look on my question again I have updated with the detailed code which I have written.

Comment: You need to change the elif I have circled to an else and indent the two sections as per the circled area [Imgur Link](http://imgur.com/heo7cWx)

Comment: I already did this I had replaced my this code of section with yours. But still it doesn't work for me

Comment: Did you look at the imgur link? [LINK](http://imgur.com/heo7cWx) you are missing the indents on the inside if function.

Comment: Yeah I saw that link . You are talking about the indents. What I'm doing is using the tab button for each statement block. And those both are indented with four spaces

Answer (score 0):

Just put a nested else statement in the if statement that is nested. Should work fine and then loop back to the first elif

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a utility function like

```
def get_float(prompt, error_message=None):
    """
    Prompt repeatedly until a float value is entered
    """
    while True:
        try:
            return float(raw_input(prompt))   # Python 2.x!
        except ValueError:
            # not a float!
            if error_message is not None:
                print(error_message)
```

then your code becomes

```
if options == 1:
    f = get_float("Please enter degrees Fahrenheit: ")
elif options == 2:
    print("2p")
elif options == 3:
    print("3p")
else:
    print("No such option!")
```